# Bypass customer profile duplication

Tags: commerce

How do you bypass customer profile duplication when editing a profile that has already been referenced on a few orders.

- I know it is a design feature to protect historic data as mentioned
  [here](http://www.bywombats.com/blog/04-12-2013/bypassing-drupal-commerce-customer-profile-duplication)
- I am editing the profile trough the ui

Is there a easy way to achieve this without module editing?

Comment: Without hacking the module, a lot, there's no way to remove that feature (and I stress the word 'feature' there). Saving historical order information is vital so the workflow they've chosen is completely correct IMO. You could try opening up a feature request for the module though I doubt it'll get too far - as I say, they've already got it right and to change or provide an alternative would be a lot of work for little conceivable gain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you've already linked my article on the topic, I'll just answer definitively here that there is no way to do this through the user interface. The code I show in that article is the only way to bypass customer profile duplication, but if you wanted to you could apply it to a user interface in a custom module. Just be careful you don't give administrators more control than is safe for your historical order data.